# Sync Gateway no longer sync widht the client, error "406 Response is multipart"

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

What exactly does the error message "406 Response is multipart" and how can I solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

**406 NOT ACCEPTABLE**

> The target resource does not have a current representation that would
>   be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive
>   negotiation header fields received in the request1, and the server is
>   unwilling to supply a default representation.
>
> The server SHOULD generate a payload containing a list of available
>   representation characteristics and corresponding resource identifiers
>   from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate.
>   A user agent MAY automatically select the most appropriate choice from
>   that list. However, this specification does not define any standard
>   for such automatic selection

Source: https://httpstatuses.com/406

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when I login width the same user from different devices, which damages the user, after this SyncGateway does not synchronize with the user.